# ASP.NET Web API method for both GET and POST

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have the following method in my API:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage ExecuteCommand()
{
    // logic
}
```

This method currently serves only the http GET method. I would also like it to respond to http POST method - Is that possible? or do I have to duplicate the method?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public HttpResponseMessage ExecuteCommand()
{
    // logic
}
```

This is possible since the constructor looks like this, and takes an array of strings.

```
public AcceptVerbsAttribute(
    params string[] verbs
)
```